# How Can I run automatic code cleanup in VS 2022 on just the modified lines on save?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, code-cleanup

I found the code cleanup options but I want to apply them **only** on lines that have been edited and not the entire file.  Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Why only on the changed line?

Comment: Because I don't want to change others code when I edit a file. For example I dont like to read inplicit types but thats convinient to write it than save and the IDE change it automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible with the resharper extension